# Asp.Net MVC5 passing anonymous object in TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass anonymous object from controller method to show action feedback message to user such as flash message using TempData but I am getting error -'object' does not contain a definition for 'status',How should I do it?

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(FriendFormViewModel friendViewModel)
        {
         TempData["feedback"] = new { status = "success", message = "Success in action" };
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

View :

```
 @if (TempData["feedback"] != null)
{
    var f = (dynamic)TempData["feedback"];
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible action-alert @(f.status)">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <p>succes</p>
    </div>}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the exact code you're using (you copied and pasted it here) and that this is where the exception is actually be raised from? As long as you cast to `dynamic` as you've done here, you should not be getting this error.

Comment: Hi chris ,I just shortened the cotroller action method code as it was quite long and view is partial view and its same as pasted above,exception was raiised in partial view @(f.status), i just realise now it should be @f.status instead?not sure will try again and post full code if couldnot fix .

Comment: No, that won't affect anything. The `@()` syntax means the same as just `@`. It's just a way of better differentiating between Razor code and regular text. For example, if you had `var foo = 1;` and then Razor like `@foobar`, it would be interpreted as a variable named `foobar`, where as `@(foo)bar` would correctly result in `1bar`.

Comment: Oddly, the only way I can recreate your exception is if `TempData["feedback"]` is literally set to an instance of `object`. Even if you cast the anonymous object to `object`, it still says `'<>f__AnonymousType1' does not contain a definition for 'status'`, rather than `'object'`. Regardless, the error occurs when the dynamic doesn't have the member you're trying to reference. Somehow, some way, `TempData[feedback]` is being overwritten or simply set to something else.